# Changing width of Image in UIImageView in Objective C

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm attempting to resize a progress bar in an iOS app to represent an amount of time remaining.
Currently, I'm using the code within the View Controller:

```
self.allisonHall.frame = CGRectMake(self.allisonHall.frame.origin.x, 
                                    self.allisonHall.frame.origin.y,                                     
                                    self.allisonHall.frame.size.width*self.allisonHall.newWidth,
                                    self.allisonHall.frame.size.height);
self.allisonHall.contentMode=UIViewContentModeLeft;
self.allisonHall.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

where the newWidth property is a scale by which to reduce the current width (280). It's currently set at .2, and when debugging I find that the resulting width is 56.000. However, the image is not resizing.

Is it possible to change the image within the image view in this way? Or should I be using two UIImageViews?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
CGRect frame = self.allisonHall.frame;
// Not sure where you are calculating the newWidth value, debug it and make sure it has the correct value before 
frame.size.width = self.allisonHall.frame.size.width*self.allisonHall.newWidth;
self.allisonHall.frame = frame;

self.allisonHall.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;//UIViewContentModeLeft
self.allisonHall.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I'm still having the same issue. I debug for
    self.allisonHall.frame.size.width
at the end of viewDidLoad and I'm getting 56.000 as expected. It just seems that the image itself is not redrawing.

Comment: Sorry, still having the same issue.
    NSLog(@"%f", self.allisonHall.frame.size.width)
results in 56.0000, but the image in the view is still its original width. I'm thinking that it's likely I have incorrectly linked the image view.

In the view controller's .h file, the image view in question is defined as
`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet XYZdiningHall *allisonHall;`
where XYZdiningHall is a subclass of UIImageView. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Is the `IBOutlet` linked correctly from the inspector ?

Comment: The IBOutlet is linked to the view controller.
The line `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet XYZdiningHall *allisonHall;` is present in the .h file of the DiningHallViewController, the view.

Comment: I guess the main issue is why the width is equal to 56.00000 but the visual representation of it on the UI has a different width.

Comment: You should provide more code to get help. Are you trying to change the frame in an asynchronous thread (background thread) ?

Comment: I'm trying to load the width during viewDidLoad.

`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadInitialData];
    [self setBars];

}`

which calls setBars, the function using the resizing method you suggested.
Is this an issue with threading?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` gets called once. Based on your code, all I can ask you to check is the value of the width each time you assume it get changed. Otherwise, please provide more code snippet of `viewDidLoad``

Comment: When including an NSLog in the viewDidLoad function (`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.allisonHall getIsOpen];
    [self loadInitialData];
    [self setBars];
    NSLog(@"%f",self.allisonHall.frame.size.width);

}`), the result is 56.00000. 

Should I be calling the setBars method before viewDidLoad?